# Problem with category conditional

Tags: conditionals

I always seem to run into some problems with conditionals. The code in question is this:

```
{categories}
{if category_id != "305|325"}

Index version 1

{/if}

{if category_id == "305|325"}

Index version 2

{/if}
{/categories}
```

At the moment, it is always returning version 1 of the index, even when the category of the entry matches 305 or 325.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, for OR conditionals you must use one of the following:

```
{if category_id != 305 OR category_id != 325}

{if category_id != 305 || category_id != 325}
```

also, please double check that you don't need to use AND instead of OR. I've tripped myself up with that many times - especially when using negative comparison.

```
{if category_id != 305 AND category_id != 325}
     index 1 ---- the cat id is not 305 AND it is not 325
{if:else}
     index 2  --- all other cat ids
{/if}
```

OR...

```
{if category_id == 305 OR category_id == 325}
     index 2  ---- the cat id is 305 OR it is 325
{if:else}
     index 1 ---- all others
{/if}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, it was both the way the conditionals were formed and the use of OR instead of AND!